# how to install and open .exe/.msi application in ubuntu 18.04 on VM (windows host))

Tags: wine

I'm trying to install `.msi`  file in Ubuntu by using wine64 `msiexec /i setup.msi` but it shows successfully installed and two files are created in desktop. Desktop configuration file and lnk file.but I am getting errors like:

```
mangoh@mangoh-vm:~/Desktop/img/snapshot/Setup/Debug$ wine msiexec /i setup.msi
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {00021401-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} not registered
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {00021401-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} could be created for context 0x1
0009:err:msi:ITERATE_CreateShortcuts CLSID_ShellLink not available
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {00021401-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} not registered
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {00021401-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} could be created for context 0x1
0009:err:msi:ITERATE_CreateShortcuts CLSID_ShellLink not available
```

Comment: Wine can handle many Windows syscalls, but not all. Looks like your application might be part of the 'not all'

Comment: The Windows installer .msi file may be for an app which WineHQ has found to be problematic with WINE. You can confirm that by searching for that app at https://appdb.winehq.org/ . Also, are you running Ubuntu within a virtual machine?

Comment: yes,I am running ubuntu in virtual machine.